# problem with internet explorer showing html input button which is hidden

Tags: css, vb.net

I have a vb.net program that has a web browser control, and we all know that it is using the web browser in the computer before internet explorer. And my problem is, it doesn't recognize this css code:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {

    input[type=button] { display: none; }

}
```

I used that to make the print button invisible when I print the web page.
How do I fix this one?Is it possible to add a reference to a portable web browser like firefox, then it will be used by the web browser control in vb.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE < 7 doesn't know the `[attribute=value]` selector. You will have to use a class.

[**Quirksmode compatibility table**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Comment: @user225 I edited it, it applies to IE < 7 only. You would have to give the button a class `<input type='button' class='type_button'>` and make that class invisible: `input.type_button { display: none }`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use another method to hide the element, via a classname or ID;

```
.hideme { display:none }
```

To which you would add the classname:

```
<input type="button" name="authcode" value="Foo" class="hideme" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about getting VB.Net to use a different web browser, but IE 6 doesn’t understand CSS attribute selectors (i.e. `[type=button]`).

If you can amend the HTML to add a class to the `<input>` (e.g. `<input type="button" class="button">`), then you can hide it with this: `input.button { display: none; }`.